# How to run ng test before ng build --prod and fail jenkins job when ng test fails?

Tags: angular, jenkins, angular-cli

Earlier I used systemJS version of angular-cli and whenever I used to kick a build from jenkins, the build used to fail if there were any test case failure.

I just had `ng build --prod` command to build my project.

Now with webpack version of angular-cli, we have to explicitly run `ng test`.

How can I check in jenkins whether `ng test`  have succeeded and continue with `ng build --prod` or else fail the build?

Comment: were you able to figure out how to do this ?

Comment: Not really, However, I am using stage('Unit Test'){`sh 'ng test'` } before stage('Prod Build') { `sh 'ng build -prod'`} in my Jenkinsfile

Answer (score 9):

You can create a npm script like below to fail your build in case the tests fail:

```
"scripts" : {
    "cibuild": "ng test --code-coverage && ng build --prod --no-progress"
 }
```

The above is assuming you have `singleRun: true` in your karma.conf.js file.
Then you can run `npm run cibuild` which will first run tests and then build only if tests pass. We use this for our CI build through Jenkins followed by a Sonar scan.

Comment: which file does this script go in?

Comment: You can add it to package.json. It contains a 'scripts' section for creating shortcuts for longer commands

Comment: Is it possible to wrap the watcher around this too though so it tests and builds then watches and repeats continuously as you develop?

Comment: I suppose you can just run `ng test` with `single-run:false` in your karma.conf to continue development and tests with live reload. Though I am not sure if this is exactly what you are asking.